# How to kill a process whose pid keeps changing?

Tags: c, linux, unix, process

I know I can use the trick `if (fork()) exit(0);` to change the pid of the current process. So, the following program would have a pid changing very quickly. How to kill a process like this? Is there some better method than executing a lot of `killall procname` until one get able to run `kill()` before it forks? I know it is not a 'process', but many processes that run for a few microseconds each.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t self = getpid();
    while (1)
    {
        if (fork()) exit(0);
        if (self + 10000 < getpid()) break; // Just to kill it after some time
        usleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also the only way I found to list the process was executing `ps -A | grep procname` a few times until one showed some output. Why isn't the process always listed?

Comment: Who would vote to close this as "off topic"?  I mean, seriously, this isn't programming related?  What is wrong with those of you which makes you so close-happy?  Yeesh.

Comment: Is there any practical reason for writing a program that way?  It seems more like malware than anything useful.

Comment: I haven't downvoted (yet) but what exactly *is* the programming question?  It seems like you are just asking for an easy way to find and kill a process from the command line.

Comment: What I'm looking for is to understand how can a process like this be killed given the linux enviroment. I don't want to actually kill it, just understand the process. An 'easy way' command line isn't it.

Comment: Kill it from inside the program or from the external environment?

Comment: isn't there a pid for the top level process that does the forking?

Comment: From outside. As far as I can see, the only constant information between the processes is it's executable name. The toplevel process kills itself right after the forking, how it's pid could help?

Comment: @EdS.: I think it's more of a system-administration question than a programming question, but as it involves the intricacies of POSIX process and process group semantics, I also think it's relevant here, so I haven't voted to close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such a process is called a "comet" by systems administrators.

The process group ID (PGID) doesn't change on fork, so you can kill it (or `SIGSTOP` it) by sending a signal to the process group (you pass a negated PGID instead of a PID to `kill`).

Comment: What if it calls `setpgid`/`setsid` each time too? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see why you wouldn't see it is that the forked child has not been created yet but the parent has progressed far enough in it's death that it is no longer listed.

Unfortunately I don't think it's possible to kill this kind of process without some guessing. To do so would require knowing the next pid in advance. You can guess the next pid but not be certain that no other pid gets it assigned.