# Can't kill celery workers

Tags: celery

Try as I might I cannot kill these celery workers.

I run:

```
celery --app=my_app._celery:app status
```

I see I have 3 (I don't understand why 3 workers = 2 nodes, please explain if you know)

> celery@ip-x-x-x-x: OK
> celery@ip-x-x-x-x: OK
> celery@named-worker.%ip-x-x-x-x: OK
>
> 2 nodes online.

I run (as root):

```
ps auxww | grep 'celery@ip-x-x-x-x' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

The workers just keep reappearing with a new PID.

Please help me kill them.

Answer (score 10):

A process whose pid keeps changing is called `comet`. Even though pid of this process keeps on changing, its process group ID remains constant. So you can kill by sending a signal.

```
ps axjf | grep '[c]elery' | awk '{print $3}' | xargs kill -9
```

Alternatively, you can also kill with `pkill`

```
pkill -f celery
```

This kills all processes with fullname `celery`.

[Reference: killing a process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13655416/2698552)

Comment: Thanks for comment, but I tried this and it still din't kill them

Answer (score 3):

```
pkill -f celery
```

Run from the command line, this will kill at processes related to celery.

Answer (score 2):

1. In your console, type :

```bash
ps -aux | grep celery
```

I get :

```bash
simon    24615  3.8  0.6 344276 219604 pts/3   S+   22:53   0:56 /usr/bin/python3 /home/simon/.local/bin/celery -A worker_us_task worker -l info -Q us_queue --concurrency=30 -n us_worker@%h
```

2. select what you find after **-A** and type :

```bash
pkill -9 -f 'worker_us_task worker'
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use:

```
ps auxww | grep 'celery' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

If you're using `supervisord` to run celery, you need to kill `supervisord` process also.